# What ports should I open to use EC2 as a nameserver (I thought I knew, but apparently not!)

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, bind

I have an EC2 micro instance running with the Amazon linux. I installed bind and set up an entry for a certain domain, and it works fine if you are on that server and type:

nslookup the-domain.com localhost

but I can't get to it from external servers by typing

nslookup the-domain.com 10-10-10-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com

In my security group, I set it to allow incoming traffic on port 53 (both TCP and UDP) but still, nothing. Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: should be 10-10-10-10.compute-1.ec2.amazonaws.com

Comment: "should be 10-10-10-10.compute-1.ec2.amazonaws.com – BenGC 2 hours ago" - actually nope, not in my case.

Comment: I take it you have verified the hostname, the format I have usually seen is: ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com  You can get it from `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname` (run from your instance) [Side note: since AWS DNS names include the IP, the '10' at the start implies a private DNS - just double check that you have the public DNS]

Comment: yeah that's my bad. sorry!

Comment: Is bind listening on an interface other than the loopback? For example can you do a lookup against the physical IP address while on the instance, as opposed to against 'localhost'?

Comment: I can't do a lookup on the physical IP while on the instance, no, I can only do it using localhost.

Comment: (also about cyberx86's sidenote, the IP does not start in 10, I just threw those in for a quick example, didn't realize 10 meant private DNS, my bad!)

Comment: netstat will also tell you on what IP addresses bind is listening. If it is not listening on the physical IP address you will need to reconfigure it to do so otherwise your lookups will not work form other machines. What is the value for 'listen-on' in your named.conf?

Comment: AHHH solved, I had "listen-on" set wrong, I thought I changed it, but maybe that was on the previous instance, agh. Thanks, that did it, woo! (well there's still some error, but that was obviously the main one )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Check AWS Security Group*

Log into the aws management console, click on the EC2 tab, click on Security Groups in Navigation section on the left.

Security Groups is where you manage a virtual firewall for your instances.  Has nothing to do with the OS running on the instance.

At one time you were restricted to changing security groups that were not assigned.  Now you can make changes to groups assigned to live instances and they will be applied immediately.

*Check Bind Configuration*

By default, bind only listens on 127.0.0.1.  Make sure you are listening on all interfaces.  Edit /etc/named.conf, change appropriate line to:

```
listen-on port 53 { any; };
```

Then restart the service.

```
service named restart
```

To confirm *named* is listening to "everything", use netstat like so.

```
[root@...]# netstat -nlp | grep named
tcp        0      0 10.1.7.152:53            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8664/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8664/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8664/named
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                  :::*                        LISTEN      8664/named
udp        0      0 10.1.7.152:53            0.0.0.0:*                               8664/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53             0.0.0.0:*                               8664/named
```

Look for named listening on the network accessible interfaces (in this case 10.1.7.152).

Comment: Yeah, I actually did that too, created another instance in case the security groups update didn't take effect if you did it AFTER launching an instance, but still no luck. I guess I wasn't clear on that too, but the first thing I did to try and make this work was add port 53 TCP and UDP to my security group, but it didn't do anything (I did do this for port 80 the other day on a different instance and it worked, so I know what I'm SUPPOSED to be doing in there)

Comment: I just tested this out on a fresh instance with a restricted security group.  Installed and started dnsmasq, added dns ports to the security group and it worked immediately from a remote (non-aws) system.  Sounds more like a bind configuration problem.

Comment: Tested bind myself, worked fine but I did need to change the default configuration.  Updated answer to reflect things to check.

Answer (score 0):

Check for firewalls which may be blocking the port(s).

Comment: Firewalls where though? I don't think EC2 has any installed by default in their linux distro

Comment: Start with the local instance with a test against the loopback (127.0.0.1)/localhost address for access.

Comment: I can do an nslookup while logged into the instance if I just type:  nslookup yahoo.com localhost

Comment: How about a telnet to port 53 of the system from another EC2 instance (possibly in addition to what h0w1r3 has identified) - which is working/troubleshooting outward from the system?

Comment: Yeah, telnetting to it does not work, either from a differnet EC2 instance or a whole non-Amazon server. I also tried using the internal hostname from the other EC2 instance, same thing, no dice. If I telnet to localhost on the actual machine I am talking about, I do get connected on port 53 though.

Comment: security groups ?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have an firewall rules that may be blocking you DNS server.

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

If you get any output check to see if you are allowing input on port 53 in this format it would be something like

```
102 11468 ACCEPT   udp  --  any  any   anywhere           anywhere       udp dpt:domain
 20  1013 ACCEPT   tcp  --  any  any   anywhere           anywhere       tcp dpt:domain
```

If you need to enable port 53 then you can do this like so

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but no luck so far, nothing showed up in iptables, but I ran those commands anyway and it shows the proper lines for those 2 rules now, but still nothing doing, can't connect